# How to describe the situation that reverse the reason and result?

Tags: sentence

For example:

A: My wage is low so I do my work slowly

B: No! Your wage is low just because you do your work slowly, you xxxxxx(some words or sentences to describe reverse the reason and result)

How to describe the situation in xxxxxx properly?

Comment: ["affirming the consequent."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent)  If my wage is low, I work slowly.   (P->Q)  No!  You work slowly, then your wage is low. (Q->P)  ... though I'm describing B here.  A is just mixing up cause and effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'*Backwards*, *back-to-front*, or *the wrong way round*.

A: My wage is low so I do my work slowly

B: No! Your wage is low *because* you work slowly. You've got it *backwards/back-to-front/the wrong way round*.

Answer (score 0):

Converse

> adjective
>   1.
>   opposite or contrary in direction, action, sequence, etc.; turned around.
>   - dictionary.com

However, you apply the word to the argument, not the person. "B: It's the converse - your wage is low because ...". In formal logic, the converse of "A implies B" is "B implies A".

Alternatively, you could use the phrase "on the contrary". "B: On the contrary - your wage is low because ...".